# waf create task from within executing task

Tags: task, schedule, waf

How can I start a task from within another task calling a different task class.

```
@feature('unites')
@after_method('apply_link')
def make_test_unites(self):
    if getattr(self, 'link_task', None):
        tsk = self.create_task('unites', self.link_task.outputs)
        tsk.a = []

@feature('gtester')
@after_method('apply_link')
def make_test_gtester(self):
    if getattr(self, 'link_task', None):
         tsk = self.create_task('gtester', self.link_task.outputs)

class unites (Task.Task):
    def runnable_status(self):
        ### print("Never reached!")
        ...

    def run(self):
        ...
        ### print("Never reached!")
        ...


class gtester (Task.Task):
     def runnable_status(self):
         //works as expected

     def run(self):
         ...
         bld = self.generator.bld
         ...
         #utask = unites(env=bld.env)
         utask = self.generator.create_task ('unites')
         assert (utask)
         utask.set_inputs(self.generator.link_task.outputs)
         utask.a = ["some foo extra stuff"]
         #bld.add_to_group (utask)

         ### print ("this is definitily reached")
```

So the code does not crash but when I use `./waf --zones=task_gen,tasks` all I get is the one task for `gtester`, but none for `unites`.

This is how it is used in practice:

```
test = bld.program(
    features = ['c', 'glib2', 'gtester'],
            ...,
            ...
            )
```

Have had a deep look into [the waf book](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_16/single.html) and the API docs, but neither did yield anything useful.

**So how can I schedule a task (or any number of tasks) from an already running task?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use

```
 tsk = self.generator.create_task('unites')
 bld.producer.outstanding.insert(0, tsk)
 bld.producer.total += 1
```

And `./waf --zones=tasks` shows the additional tasks.

---

Inspired by in the waf svn repo under `./waf/playground/dynamic_headers/wscript`

---

A thing to mention: The `[M/N]` task count infront of each line will suddenly jump up when `gtester` is processed, which is due to the fact that the total count gets updated at the end of a `Task` so waf can not know about the total number until then.